I cannot upload multiple files in my html template
I am making a site where you can send your game with multiple additional images. I upload images and they are send to API. Then when you open the game page there is a request to API and it returns the image. The problem is that when I try to upload multiple images only last one uploads. This is my html form
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<form id="chloroform" action="/senddata" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data >
  <h2>Загрузить игру</h2>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Основные данные</legend>
      <label for="title">Название игры:</label>
      <input type="text" name="title"  id="title" maxlength="24" required>
  </fieldset>

      <div class="container col-md-6" style="float:right; position: relative; top: -100px; left: 20px">
    <p style="outline:2px solid #555; border-radius:5px; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
        <img id="frame" src="" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px;  " />
    </p>

    <div class="mb-5">
        <input class="form-control" name="prev" type="file" id="formFile" onchange="preview()" accept="image/png" required>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkImage(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (file.type === 'image/png') {
                const img = new Image();
                img.onload = () => {
                    if (img.width === img.height) {
                        resolve();
                    } else {
                        reject(new Error('Изображение должно быть квадратным!'));
                    }
                };
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            } else {
                reject(new Error('Изображение должно быть в формате PNG!'));
            }
        });
    }

    function preview() {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        checkImage(file)
            .then(() => {
                const frame = document.getElementById('frame');
                frame.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                frame.style.display = 'block';
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(error.message);
                document.getElementById('formFile').value = null;
                const frame = document.getElementById('frame');
                frame.src = '';
                frame.style.display = 'none';
            });
    }
</script>

<!-- THIS IS IMAGES WHERE I GET THE PROBLEM-->
  <fieldset>
      <legend>Additional data</legend>
      <div>
          <textarea name="desc" placeholder="Brief description" id="desc" style="width: 312px; height: 150px;" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>

      </div>
  </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <legend for="file" class="form-label">Zip file </legend>
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" name="file" id="file" type="file" accept=".zip" required>
            <script>
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(e) {
    if(!e.target.files[0].name.match(/\.(zip)$/)) {
        alert('Only .zip!');
        e.target.value = '';
    }
};
</script>
        </div>
<div>
    <legend for='files'>Select additional images: </legend>
    <label>Only png!</label>
    <input id='files' type='file' class="btn btn-outline-info" name="files" accept="image/png" multiple>
</div>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <button  type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}

And here i try to retrieve the data
@app.route('/senddata', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def senddata():
    url = f"{api_url}/games"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form.get('title')
        desc = request.form.get('desc', '')
        author = int(current_user.get_id())
        prev_file = request.files['prev']
        zip_file = request.files['file']
        files = request.files.getlist('files')
        if not prev_file.filename.endswith('.png'):
            prev_file = open('url_for(static, filename=images/default.png)', 'rb')
        images = []
        for file in files:
            if file.filename.lower().endswith('.png'):
                images.append(("png", file.read()))
                print('Check')
        data = {
            "title": title,
            "desc": desc,
            "author": author,
            "prev": ("png", prev_file.read()),
            "file": ("zip", zip_file.read()),
            "images": images
        }
        requests.post(url, data=pickle.dumps(data)).json()
        return redirect('/index')

And here I try to use the data
<div id="info" style="width: 48vw">
    <p id="infoframe" style="outline:2px solid #555; border-radius:5px; width: 100%; min-height: 15vw;">
        {{game['desc']}}
    </p>
    <div id="imgframe" style="width: 100%">
        <div id="images" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel" style="width: max-content; margin: auto">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                {% for image in game['images'] %}
                <div class="carousel-item {% if loop.first %}active{% endif %}">
                    <img src="{{api_url}}/file?p={{image['img']}}" class="d-block w-100" style="max-width: 20vw;max-height: 20vw;">
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#images" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Предыдущая</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#images" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Следующая</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I am kind of a newbie to python and html so I kind of do not understand how this works and why it doesn't work as inteded.
I have seen that I need multiple so I used it in
<input id='files' type='file' class="btn btn-outline-info" name="files" accept="image/png" multiple>

but it still sent only the last image

I am sorry if I made this question too long and complex :(

Your question isn't about Django, I've taken a guess that the code you share is for Flask and closed it with a duplicate for that. If not please [edit] this question and tag it with the appropriate framework / library and ping me. This is at least not Django.
